# How to change all lines consisting of one "0" character to something else?

Tags: sed

I have a file with lines similar to the below:

```
0
0.1
0.0002
0
0.30
```

I want to replace the lines with a single `0` to something else like `0.0001`. For the lines with a decimal and digits after, I don't want to alter them.

I've tried the below variations of `sed`, but it either does nothing, or it changes all the zeros, even ones after the decimals:

```
sed 's/0/x/g' file
sed 's/^0/x/g' file
sed 's/0^/x/g' file
sed 's/^0^/x/g' file
sed 's/"0"/x/g' file
sed 's/[0]/x/g' file
```

It seems `sed` cannot handle a single `0` character. Also, I do not have the `replace` command on my system. What else can I do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To replace a single 0 on a line:

```
sed 's/^0$/x/'
```

^ matches the beginning of the line

$ matches the end of a line

So the above command matches the beginning of a line, followed by 0, followed by the end of the line.

Comment: No need for `g` modifier..

Comment: @heemayl if there are multiple lines with just 0 on the surely you would need the g modifier?

Comment: The whole sed command applies to *every* line of the file. The g modifier means to replace multiple patterns in the line.

Comment: Ah ha yes. I've been playing with lots of files with long wrapped lines recently!

Comment: @forquare No, `g` moidifier is needed as `g` is onlyt need for multiple updates per line.  multiple lines are automatically supported.

Answer (score 4):

Using Awk:

```
awk '{gsub(/^0$/,0.0001)};1' file
```